# Return progress to Jenkins pipeline sh step

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm developing a Jenkins job using Pipeline plugin.

Jenkins draws a nice GUI showing overall progress bar and progress bars for each stage. From my observations, it updates progress bars based on average running time that it has estimated from previous launches.

Here is the example: 
[image]

The last step of my job (Run) is very long. This step runs some utility program that can estimate its progress, and currently prints it to stdout.

So I can open logs from that step and see the actual progress.

However, this progress doesn't match with Jenkins' estimate.

Are there any ways to pass utility's estimate of the progress to the Jenkins so it could update progress bar accordingly?

Comment: From my understanding, this is determined based on the previous run's execution time. I'm not aware of an API to update the progress - although I think that would be pretty neat.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I haven't found any solution.

Answer (score -2):

You could solve your issue by rewriting the long-running step in Groovy and adding printouts in between shorter steps.

Instead of e.g.

`stage('very_long_stage') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            println "Running very long stage"
                            sh "make all"
                        }
                    }
                }`

you  could have e.g.

`stage('very_long_stage') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            println "Running long step 1"
                            sh "make one"
                            println "Running long step 2"
                            sh "make two"
                            // etc.
                        }
                    }
                }`

Comment: Do you mean that these `println`s are interpreted as progress indication? Will I get progress bar updates?

Comment: Have tried - this doesn't work. I can see printed messages, but no progress bar updates.